# is it possible to have an unclickable or click-through window in electron?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm making an app that just tallies the amount of files in a folder and presents a percentage number on the top left of a person's screen. It's purely visual and I would like to make it so that you can still click on things below it, so that it doesn't interfere with other programs. how is this achieved?

Comment: This article may give you some pointers for the Windows OS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BrowserWindow function :

> setIgnoreMouseEvents(boolean)

A simple example, given BrowserWindow ***win***, can be:

```
win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
```